# Database structure for storing a statement and 4 options with inline images

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have a statement which can have multiple inline block images (like say mathematical formulaes) and has 4 associated choices (like in a quiz) and each one of them can have any number of inline images as well.

I know in a naive manner I can store HTML for each of them

```
Q_ID|Ques|Number Of Choices| Choice A | Choice B | Choice C | Choice D
```

or we can have a Question Table

```
Q_ID|Ques| Q_contains_image| Number Of Choices| Choice A | Choice ID| Choice_contains_image| Choice B | ....Choice C... | Choice D ...
```

and an image table

```
Img_Id|Q_ID/CHoice_ID|Image_path
```

I still don't know if they are the best way and how will the second way affect the performance if we need to render the question with the choices in HTML. I don't like the first way because that would require hardcoding the path within the HTML and HTML is never nice to read when you see them as a result of an sql query.

I want to know some good method to store them along with what would be implied costs of using a good method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the data.  By normalizing the data, we eliminate redundancy in the data and reduce the storage needed to the minimum.

You do need to join tables to get at all of the information.  Joining tables is what relational databases were designed to do, so they join tables quickly.

```
Question
--------
Question ID
Question Text

Answer
------
Answer ID
Question ID
Answer Text

Correct Answer
--------------
Correct Answer ID
Question ID
Answer ID

Question Image
--------------
Question Image ID
Question ID
Question Image

Answer Image
------------
Answer Image ID
Answer ID
Answer Image
```

In each of the above tables, the first ID field is the primary (clustering) key.  The primary key is an auto-incrementing integer or long.

Any ID fields after the first field are foreign keys pointing back to the table with the primary key.

In the Correct Answer table, you have an additional unique index on (Question ID, Answer ID).

You don't store HTML in any of the database columns.  You store text or images.

Edited to answer the questions in the comments.

> Should I have a flag for the image in the question/image table or you suggest that I deduce it on the basis of getting a match or no match from the image table.

You deduce it on the basis of getting a row or no row from the image table.

> What do you mean by correct answer id. Suppose I have a question with choices a,b,c,d and a,b are correct. How do you propose I feed that data here?

If you have more than one correct answer for a question, you have more than one row in the Correct Answer table.  The Question ID would be the same for both rows in your example, white the Answer IDs would point to the two correct answers.

Comment: Should I have a flag for the image in the question/image table or you suggest that I deduce it on the basis of getting a match or no match from the image table.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the correct answer table. What do you mean by correct answer id. Suppose I have a question with choices a,b,c,d and a,b are correct. How do you propose I feed that data here? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @R1234: See the answers to your questions in the edited answer.